# Jquery issue while retrieving textbox name from wordpress widget box

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When i tried to retrieve the textbox name from a wordpress widget using jquery, it shows incorrect name.This is the actual textbox in the widget form

< input type="text" value="" name="widget-nw_widget[3][heading][]" class="widefat" >

whereas when I alert the name of this field using jquery it shows `widget-nw_widget[__i__][heading][]`.

This is the jquery used for getting the name attribute

```
alert( jqry( '.widget-content #ne_container .widefat' ).attr("name") );
```

Comment: It works fine for me, you might want to create a minimal test case or give us a live URL on where to check this.

Comment: I think php renders [3][heading][] with some values i.e. [__i__]